# useSelector() is showing promise instead of updated value from store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using `react-redux` with `@reduxjs/toolkit` for global state management and in my store I have `sliceOne` with initial state and reducer. I am trying to use the state value in a component with `useSelector()` but it is showing promise instead of updated value. I dispatch action in that component.

store/sliceOne.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const sliceOne = createSlice({
  name: "sliceOne",
  initialState: {
    firstName: "first",
    lastName: "last",
    age: 10,
    product: {},
  },
  reducers: {
    async action1(state) {
      const res = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/2`);
      const data = await res.json();
      state.product = data;
    },
  },
});

export const sliceOneActions = sliceOne.actions;

export default sliceOne;
```

component

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { sliceOneActions } from "../store/slice-one";

const Compo = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(dispatch(sliceOneActions.action1()), []); // without calling this getting state value but with this getting promise

  let data = useSelector((state) => state);
  console.log(data);  //getting promise

  return <div></div>;
};

export default Compo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

1. Reducer functions are to be considered pure, ***synchronous*** functions. If you need to run some asynchronous logic then you need to handle this in an ***asynchronous*** action, a.k.a. Thunk.
2. The component is incorrectly using the `useEffect` hook by directly calling `dispatch` in place of the `useEffect` hook callback function.

## Solution

Move the asynchronous logic from the reducer function into an asynchronous action.

1. Create an [asynchronous Thunk function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) that makes the GET request and returns the fetched data.
2. Add a case reducer in the `sliceOne` slice's `extraReducers` to handled a fulfilled `action1` action Promise.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const action1 = createAsyncThunk(
  "sliceOne/action1",
  async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/2");
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
  }
);

const sliceOne = createSlice({
  name: "sliceOne",
  initialState: {
    firstName: "first",
    lastName: "last",
    age: 10,
    product: {},
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase((action1.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.product = action.payload;
      }));
  },
});

export const sliceOneActions = {
  ...sliceOne.actions,
  action1,
};

export default sliceOne;
```

Fix the UI to correctly use the `useEffect` hook to dispatch the `action1` action.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { sliceOneActions } from "../store/slice-one";

const Compo = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(sliceOneActions.action1());
  }), []);

  const data = useSelector((state) => state);

  ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
reducers: {
  action1: (state, action) => {
    ...state,
    product: action.payload
  }
},
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function getProducts() {
    const res = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/2`);
    const data = await res.json();
    dispatch(sliceOneActions.action1(data))
  }
  getProducts();
}, []);
```